# Custom transition for different devices with react-multi-carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-multi-carousel

I am building a carousel with react multi carousel. So far the package is really great and did a lot of the heavy lifting for me. There is just a tiny thing that I guess I am missig. Is there a proper way of setting different value for a different device type on the "customTransition" porperty? Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-device-detect lib to determine the device type

```js
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

...

<Carousel
   customTransition={
     isMobile ? "yout custom transition for mobile" : "your custom transition for desktop"
   }
>
```

Comment: Thanks! i considred this one and it works for me, although I kind of think that there have to be e different aproach to this (like using the carousel state which for example is received if you use a custom button group). I am trying to figure out how to use this carousel state in the parent component (where I am including the carousel component). As the docs says there is deviceType prop which usage is not well documented.